# CodeIgniter sub-sub-folder controller works localhost but not on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having troubles with this structure only on server environment:

```
controllers    
    -> Controller_home.php    
    -> folder 1/
      -> Controller_1.php
      -> Controller_2.php
      -> folder 2/
        -> Controller_3.php
```

`Controller.home.php` works fine

`Controller_1.php` works fine

`Controller_2.php` works fine

`Controller_3.php` doesn't work - it appears my custom 404 page error

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0 version, and previously I had trouble with the required first letter of each controllers to be uppercase. So I rename all my controllers and models files to use the first letter as uppercase.

I thought the problem I'm having now could be due to the folders inside controllers/ not be uppercase, but it ain't because of that.

I repeat that **the structure works on local environment**.

**Edit**: As requested, my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # activate URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine on

    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt)

    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>
```

My `Controller_3.php` (it's actually a Customers controller) code:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Customers extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();


    }

    public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->view('backend/customers/index');
    }
}
?>
```

**Edit 2:**
My complete (so far) route file:

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes']                  = TRUE;
$route['default_controller']                    = 'home/login';
$route['404_override']                          = 'home/error';

$route['app/entities/index']                    = 'backend/entities/index';
$route['app/suppliers/index']                   = 'backend/suppliers/index';
$route['app/administration/customers/index']    = 'backend/administration/customers/index';
```

Comment: does controller1, and 2 work on your production server? or none of them do? what is the error is showing?

Comment: @jpganz18 yes, they work without any problem.

Comment: can you show the code for Controller_3?

Comment: do you perhaps have a `.htaccess` on your server thats making changes to that path?

Comment: @CodeGodie see my updated topic

Comment: can you also show all your routes in `routes.php` ?

Comment: @jpganz18 See my updated topic

Comment: @CodeGodie see my updated topic

Comment: I dont think this will fix your issue, but you should leave the default routes (translate_uri_dashes, default_controller, 404_override) on the very bottom and the ones you create on top, as this is read from top to bottom.

Comment: @CodeGodie I have changed from top to bottom and didn't help.

Comment: Just tested this with CI3 on my server and it works ok. Local works, server works. I just had to make sure it wasnt CI.

Comment: Do you have anything in your `application\core` folder ?

Comment: @CodeGodie nothing. I was trying the `My_Router` thing..but then I deleted. It's very strange. Btw, in my server I'm using 7.0 PHP might be because of that? Is the only thing different from the local environment

Comment: That's gotta be it. I wouldnt know why else.

Comment: @CodeGodie can we go to chat? I see something strange and it ain't because of 7.0 php version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102719/discussion-between-linesofcode-and-codegodie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a tremendous amount of debug and with the help of the fellow **@CodeGodie** by giving me tips, I end up realizing it was some problem while transfering the System/ folder to my FTP server.

I downloaded again the CodeIgniter 3.0 framework, and just copy paste the System/ folder and it started working instantly.